# How can I extract the main diagonal of a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, sparse-matrix

How can I extract the main diagonal of a sparse matrix? The matrix is created in `scipy.sparse`. I want equivalent of `np.diagonal()`, but for sparse matrix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A sparse matrix has a `diagonal` method:

```
M.diagonal()
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.diagonal.html

The numpy diagonal is a little more powerful, allowing you to specify an off diagonal

```
M.A.diagonal(2)
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks. Where can I find documentation for .A attribute that you used for the sparse matrix M?

Comment: Be careful--the `.A` attribute creates a regular (dense) numpy array.

Comment: `.A` is shorthand for `toarray()`.  It's a property, like `.T`.